# How to convert a discord message object into a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, aiml

I'm using the method **kernel.respond(message)** from the module **aiml**.

the message variable here is of type ***discord.message.Message***
but the method **kernel.respond(message)** can only have a string argument.

How can I convert the ***discord.message.Message*** object into string?

Comment: `message.content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) instance, then you can use [`content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content) to get the string representation of the message body

```
content = message.content
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to get the actual message string rather than convert the Message object into a string representation. You should look at [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to find how to do it. Specifically, the documentation of the [Message class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message) has some good information.